# When I am doing ng serve -o then getting an unhandled exception occurred: ts.createNodeArray is not a function

Tags: angular, exception, unhandled

When I am doing `ng serve -o` I am receiving (in Angular 6) this error

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ts.createNodeArray is not a function
See "C:\Users\MADHUK~1.PUL\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-V81Kkf\angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

When i open that file, it is showing like this

```
[error] TypeError: ts.createNodeArray is not a function
    at C:\Users\madhukar.pul\Desktop\Angular\employee\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\evaluator.js:670:20
    at C:\Users\madhukar.pul\Desktop\Angular\employee\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\evaluator.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\madhukar.pul\Desktop\Angular\employee\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\evaluator.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at C:\Users\madhukar.pul\Desktop\Angular\employee\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\collector.js:21:23
    at C:\Users\madhukar.pul\Desktop\Angular\employee\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\collector.js:10:17
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\madhukar.pul\Desktop\Angular\employee\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\metadata\collector.js:16:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
```

Comment: What is ng `server` ?

Comment: ng serve not ng server

Answer (score 2):

Couple of steps to try out :-

1. Re-install node_modules.
2. Check the node and typescript version. May be you need to update node or typescript vesion.

Hope this helps.